# get posts using taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a wordpress app locally setup in my computer. In the wordpress admin i have a Countries tab under the Posts. I'll attach an image for better understanding.

[image]

I want to write a function to get the country values for my front-end. For that i have written a function like this

```
    public function get_destinations()
    {

            $bookings = get_posts(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'=> 'country',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                )
            );
            return $bookings;
    }
```

But for some reason this function returns all the posts in the database. I want to get only the country names.

i found the taxonomy from my local url which is

```
http://localhost/my_project/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=country
```

I'm very new to wordpress and dont have a clue on how to retrieve these data to my front end. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the only category or taxonomy name instead of **get_posts** you have to use **get_terms**

check this code.

```
// Get the taxonomy's terms
    $terms = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'country',
            'hide_empty' => false, // show category even if dont have any post.
        )
    );

    // Check if any term exists
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
        // Run a loop and print them all
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </a><?php
        }
    }
```